# does jquery have an equivalent of dojo.hitch()?

Tags: jquery

Forgive my ignorance as I am not as familiar with jquery. Is there an equivalent to [dojo.hitch()](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/hitch.html)? It returns a function that is guaranteed to be executed in the given scope.

-- edit --
As requested, here is an example. I use hitch very frequently to ensure callbacks are executed within the right object. For example, let's say I have a utility method called `doSomethingAsync` and I pass it a callback function. With hitch, I can make sure the function is executed within a particular scope even if the utility method performs ajax calls and so forth:

```
expectedScopeObj = {
   flag: true,
   callback: function(){console.debug(this.flag);},
   main: function() {
     // without hitch the callback function would not find flag  
     core.util.doSomethingAsync(dojo.hitch(this, this.callback));
   }
}
```

Without hitch, the callback function could possibly be executed in a different scope and an error would be thrown with `this.flag` being undefined. However, with hitch it is guaranteed to be executed within `execptedScopeObj`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? A sample code would be helpful

Comment: Shouldn't the example have been dojo.hitch(this, this,callback)?

Comment: This [Hitch](https://github.com/phiggins42/bloody-jquery-plugins/blob/master/hitch.js) jQuery plugin is adapted from Dojo

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I know this has been answered, but not correctly. [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy) is what you are looking for I believe.

**UPDATE**

Many, many years later after lots of JavaScript work, and after stripping out my usage of jQuery since browser compatibility has become less of an issue, I would recommend using [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) over [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy), as [@bobince suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2035427/633513). While this is still the correct answer to the original question, I feel obligated to direct people to a vanilla solution rather than relying on jQuery.

Answer (score 6):

[**ADMIN EDIT**: Note the much more popular answer, below.—[danorton]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351201/danorton)

I'd go for `function.bind`, which will be the standard way of doing this in future versions of JavaScript. As well as fixing `this` , it allows you to pass arguments through to the target functions.

Until all browsers support it natively, you can [hack support in yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025789/preserving-a-reference-to-this-in-javascript-prototype-functions/2025839#2025839).

Comment: although bind is similar and certainly very useful, it doesn't quite accomplish the task

Comment: Erm... it accomplishes the task of calling back a function with `this` set appropriately. What else do you expect `hitch` to do? Your example code above doesn't work at all.

Comment: You're right. I misunderstood and thought you were referring to jquery's bind function. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No. Not in 1.3.2, at least, as I don't know about 1.4. There are, however, some [plugins](http://think-robot.com/2009/06/hitch-object-oriented-event-handlers-with-jquery/):

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.hitch = function(ev, fn, scope) {
    return this.bind(ev, function() {
      return fn.apply(scope || this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: We try if at all possible to avoid using plugins only because we prefer to go with the support of a base library. It looks like right now our best bet is to use a combined dojo base and jquery build so we get the best of both worlds :)

Comment: This is necromancer territory, but for anyone else who hasn't already solved this, you may wat to look at @phiggins' hitch plugin: https://github.com/phiggins42/bloody-jquery-plugins/blob/master/hitch.js

Comment: Even more zombie-like, I just reposted that link above

Answer (score 1):

The `function.bind` mentioned by bobince is a pretty useful tool.  You could use it to rewrite the hitch function pretty simply:

```
// The .bind method from Prototype.js 
if (!Function.prototype.bind) { // check if native implementation available
  Function.prototype.bind = function(){ 
    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        object = args.shift(); 
    return function(){ 
      return fn.apply(object, 
        args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))); 
    }; 
  };
}

jQuery.hitch = function(scope, fn) {
  if (typeof fn == "string") fn = scope[fn];
  if (fn && fn.bind) return fn.bind(scope);
};
```

At least based on the doc page you linked, this is how I saw the function working...

Answer (score 1):

```
//why not just:
(function($){
  $.hitch = function(scope, fn){
    return function(){
      return fn.apply(scope, arguments);
    }
  }
})(JQuery);
//This works exactly like Dojo's hitch from what I can tell.
```

Answer (score 0):

In my mind, `hitch` in Dojo is more complex,

e.g.,

```
function f(a,b,c){return a+b*c}
var newF = hitch(null,f,1,undefined,3);
newF(2) /*1+2*3*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * This is for simulate dojo.hitch.
 * @param $
 */
(function($) {
    $.hitch = function(context, func) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 
                2/*Remove context, and func*/);

        return function() {
            return func.apply(context, 
                    Array.prototype.concat.call(args, arguments));
        };
    };
})(jQuery);
```