# why 'this' is not working inside a function of a plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

```
(function($){
  $.fn.countdown = function(){

   var current = 5;
   function count(){

     this.text(current);

   }

    count();

 }
})(jQuery);
```

Why in this plugin I'm getting a console error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'text'`. 
 But if i declare `this` as a variable outside of the count function,
 for example `var this_selected = this;` and then use it inside the count function then it is working.

Comment: scope question makes my head spin, I think this inside the count function refers to the window. I am sure someone will clear this up for you

Answer (score 0):

A `javascript` variable should be declared before using it. Don't you mean `$(this)` in this case?

Comment: Not exactly. `this` outside the scope of the count function is already a jQuery object, therefore it doesn't need `$()`. Inside the count function it references `window` rather than the selected element, therefore `$(this)` isn't needed unless you want a jQuery object containing the window.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a confusing and dumb aspect of Javascript. Anyone who disagrees has spent too much time in its world.

The only time you can really know what `this` will be in a function is in one of two ways:

```
myFunc = function() {
  // I wonder what 'this' is?
}
myObj.myFunc = myFunc;

myObj.myFunc();
// ('this' will be 'myObj')   ...OR...

myFunc.apply(myObj/*, any extra arguments here*/);
// ('this' will again be 'myObj'). apply is a special method in each function object
```

On my part, the issue is solved with `dojo.hitch`, which uses `apply` internally. It sounds like the solution is a little different in JQuery. Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035236/does-jquery-have-an-equivalent-of-dojo-hitch) will help you.