# Javascript: Access the right scope "under" apply(...)

Tags: javascript, oop, scope

This is a very old problem, but I cannot seem to get my head around the other solutions presented here.

I have an object

```
function ObjA() {
    var a = 1;
    this.methodA = function() {
        alert(a);
    }
}
```

which is instantiated like

```
var myObjA = new ObjA();
```

Later on, I assign my `methodA` as a handler function in an external Javascript Framework, which invokes it using the `apply(...)` method.

When the external framework executes my `methodA`, `this` belongs to the framework function invoking my method.

Since I cannot change how my method is called, how do I regain access to the private variable `a`?

My research tells me, that *closures* might be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a closure. When `methodA` is called the access to `a` will work fine.

Object properties are a different thing to scopes. You're using scopes to implement something that behaves a *bit* like ‘private members’ in other languages, but `a` is a local variable in the parent scope, and *not* a member of `myObjA` (private or otherwise). Having a function like `methodA` retain access to the variables in its parent scope is what a ‘closure’ means.

Which scopes you can access is fixed: you can always access variables in your parent scopes however you're called back, and you can't call a function with different scopes to those it had when it was defined.

Since `a` is not a property of `this`, it doesn't matter that `this` is not preserved when calling you back. If you *do* need to get the correct `this` then yes, you will need some more work, either using another closure over `myObjA` itself:

```
onclick= function() { myObjA.methodA(); };
```

or using [Function#bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545588/javascript-using-this-in-global-object/2545627#2545627):

```
onclick= myObjA.methodA.bind(myObjA);
```

Comment: You are right. I really do have access to `a`, but I cannot verify this using Firebug. But thanks a lot for enlighting me!

Comment: You can see parent scopes and their variables in Firebug by looking inside the `scopeChain` pseudo-variable in the ‘Watch’ tab.

Comment: Yes yes, I know. But these variables does not appear in my firebug. I cannot access them in the console either - though it does not response as if they were undefined, just no response.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you're right. Instead of a method reference

```
 var myObjA = new ObjA();

 libraryCallback = myObjA.methodA
```

pass a closure

```
 libraryCallback = function() { myObjA.methodA() }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery javascript framework, easiest way is to use [proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
$('a').click($.proxy(myObjA, 'methodA'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```
function ObjA() {
    this.a = 1;
    this.methodA = function() {
        alert(this.a);
    }
}

function bindMethod(f, o) {
    return function(){
        return f.apply(o, arguments);
    }
}

var myObjA = new ObjA();
myObjA.methodA = bindMethod(myObjA.methodA, myObjA);
...
```

Where `bindMethod` binds the `methodA` method to always be a method of `myObjA` while still passing on any arguments which `function() {myObjA.methodA()}` doesn't do.