# 'this' object can't be accessed in private JavaScript functions without a hack?

Tags: javascript, this, private

I was working on a project for a while, trying to figure out what I was doing wrong, when I finally narrowed "the bug" down to the fact that the below code doesn't work as I expected:

```
function Alpha()
    {
    this.onion = 'onion';

    function Beta()
        {
        alert(this.onion);
        }

    Beta();
    }

alpha1 = new Alpha();
// Alerts 'undefined'
```

However, if I change the code to this:

```
function Alpha()
    {
    var self = this;
    this.onion = 'onion';

    function Beta()
        {
        alert(self.onion);
        }

    Beta();
    }

alpha1 = new Alpha();
// Alerts 'onion'
```

it works like I would expect.  After wasting a large portion of my life, can anyone explain why it works like this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Works like this because each function has associated its own *execution context*.

However there are other ways to do it, for example:

Using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/apply) to invoke the function:

```
function Alpha() {
  this.onion = 'onion';

  function Beta() {
    alert(this.onion);
  }

  Beta.call(this);
}

var alpha1 = new Alpha();
// Alerts 'onion'
```

The new ECMAScript 5th Edition Standard, introduces a way to persist the function *context*, the [`Function.prototype.bind`](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.3.4.5) method:

```
function Alpha() {
  this.onion = 'onion';

  var Beta = function () {
    alert(this.onion);
  }.bind(this);

  Beta();
}

var alpha1 = new Alpha();
// Alerts 'onion'
```

We can say that the `Beta` function is *bound*, and no matter how you invoke it, its `this` value will be the intact.

This method is not widely supported yet, currently only IE9pre3 includes it, but you can include [an implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025789/preserving-a-reference-to-this-in-javascript-prototype-functions/2025839#2025839) to make it work now.

Now let me elaborate about how `this` works:

The `this` value exist on each [execution context](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_10.3), and for Function Code is set implicitly when a function call is made, the value is determined depending how the *reference* if formed.

In your example, when you invoke `Beta();`, since it is not bound to any object, we can say that the reference has no *base object*, then, the `this` value will refer to the global object.

Other case happens when you invoke a function that is bound as a property of an object, for example:

```
var obj = {
  foo: function () { return this === obj;}
};
obj.foo(); // true
```

As you can see, the reference being invoked `obj.bar();` contains a base object, which is `obj`, and the `this` value inside the invoked function will refer to it.

<sub>**Note**: The [reference type](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.7) is an abstract concept, defined for language implementation purposes you can see the details in the spec.</sub>

A third case where the `this` value is set implicitly is when you use the `new` operator, it will refer to a newly created object that inherits from its constructor's prototype:

```
function Foo () {
  return this; // `this` is implicitly returned when a function is called 
}              // with `new`, this line is included only to make it obvious

var foo = new Foo();
foo instanceof Foo; // true
Foo.prototype.isPrototypeOf(foo); // true
```

Answer (score 7):

From [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, 5th Edition](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0596101996/jscript5-CHP-8-SECT-6) (the rhino book):

> When a function is invoked as a
>   function rather than as a method, the
>   `this` keyword refers to the global
>   object. Confusingly, this is true even
>   when a nested function is invoked (as
>   a function) within a containing method
>   that was invoked as a method: the `this`
>   keyword has one value in the
>   containing function but
>   (counterintuitively) refers to the
>   global object within the body of the
>   nested function.
>
> Note that `this` is a keyword, not a
>   variable or property name. JavaScript
>   syntax does not allow you to assign a
>   value to `this`.

Two things to pay attention to here:

1. `this` isn't a variable, so the normal closure capture rules don't apply.
2. `this` is "rebound" on every functiion calls, whether as a method, a normal function call, or via `new`. Since you're doing a normal function call (when calling Beta), `this` is getting bound to the "global object".

Answer (score 2):

When you call a non-member function (not called as `someObject.method()`), it runs in the context of the window.  It doesn't matter whether it's a private function or a global one.

You could do:

```
Beta.call(this);
```

[call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/call) allows you to call a function while passing a context as the first argument ([apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/apply) is similar, but the argument list is an array).

However, I'm not clear (even for the trivial example) why onion is public but Beta is private.

Comment: but if I did: var Beta = function() {alert(self.onion);}, it would give the same result, even though Beta is a private member.

Comment: That's still not a member function.  JavaScript member functions are public.

Comment: Hmm.. okay, getting confused with the terminology.  But Beta is a private member (whose value is a Function), just not a member function right?

Comment: I would say `var Beta` is a private variable, but the point is, use `someObject.method()` (calling a method *on* an object), `call`, or `apply`; `someObject` can itself be `this`.  Otherwise, it's just another function.disconnected from the object.