# Call parent function inside of click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried to make an application in JavaScript that simply creates and deletes an object, but i try to implement it with classes. The code looks like the following :

*My first file :*

```js
class GeneralObject {

    constructor(elementName) {
      this.domElement = elementName;
    }
  
    createObject() {
      $(document.createElement('span'))
        .html(this.domElement)
        .appendTo($('#someOtherElement'));
    }
  
    deleteObject() {
      this.domElement.remove();
    }
}
```

*My second file :*

```js
class SpecificObject extends GeneralObject {
  
  create() {
    
    // call the creator from parent class
    super.createObject();
    
    // create a div
    // i know the div has no expansion
    $(document.createElement('div'))
      .click(function() {
      
        // trying to call the parent function remove
        // here comes the error
        super.removeObject();
      })
      .appendTo($("#someOtherElement"));
  }
```

My goal is it to delete the object, i've created, with the click function, but i can't access the parent function in this instance. I get this error :

> 'super' keyword unexpected here

I hope you can tell me how to call my parent function in this click function. Also i look forward to an comment about this implementation via the "class" keyword, because i see everywhere only class constructs with "prototype". What is the "correct / better" way ?

Thank you for reading this post

Comment: Why would you think this is a good idea, when it's so blazingly simple to do without the classes.

Comment: @adeneo yes it could be solved with functions, but i just want to try it with classes. Its just for fun and gaining knowledge :)

Comment: @4castle Damn I'm sleepy. You're right. I don't know where I got that idea from. Time for bed, methinks.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/xppndngy/2/

Comment: You've got some inconsistent naming for `deleteObject` vs `removeObject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`super`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) is only available in instance methods. Your inner anonymous function is not an instance method, so it does not have access to it.

However, since you're using inheritance, the function will be accessible from `this`. Therefore, you can apply the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3590706/5743988) to access `this` from inside an inner function.

```
create() {
  var self = this; // get a reference to `this`

  super.createObject();

  $(document.createElement('div'))
    .click(function() {
      self.removeObject(); // `self` is `this` which inherits from `super`
    })
    .appendTo($("#someOtherElement"));
}
```

Since you're only executing a single function inside that `click` function, you can alternatively pass the function reference as a parameter:

```
$(document.createElement('div'))
    .click(super.removeObject)
    .appendTo($("#someOtherElement"));
```

Comment: I had to edit my answer because it turns out `var parent = super;` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Remember it's only prototype based after all:

```
class SpecificObject extends GeneralObject {

  constructor() {
    super();// make sure to call super since you extend
  }

  create() {

    // createObject is now available on this
    this.createObject();

    // create a div
    // i know the div has no expansion
    $(document.createElement('div'))
      // renamed from removeObject to deletedObject (typo ?) + fatArrow keep scope to the this of the instance
      .click(() => this.deleteObject())
      .appendTo($("#someOtherElement"));
  }
}
```

Comment: It's in the constructor

Comment: My bad didn't spot it. Just made the edit (wrote it with an ES6 fat arrow - you also do `var that = this` and then in the click, pass `function(){ that.deleteObject(); }`

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use something like this. This will work fine.

```
class SpecificObject extends GeneralObject {

  create() {

    // call the creator from parent class
    super.createObject();

    // create a div
    // i know the div has no expansion

  }

  }
  $(document.createElement('div'))
      .click(function() {

        // trying to call the parent function remove
        // here comes the error
        SpecificObject.removeObject();
      })
      .appendTo($("#someOtherElement"));
```

You cannot use super inside document.ready function because it's not the same class's function now.and it's not carrying the same scope of the class specificobject.

Comment: I've tried this `SpecificObject.removeObject()`, but now i get this error : _Uncaught TypeError: SpecificObject.removeObject is not a function_

Comment: Yeah and that is because you don't have any function named removeObject in your parent class, instead it is deleteObject(). can u please check that and upvote my answer or accept it..

Comment: This will not work even if the naming was correct. There's a huge difference between `SpecificObject.removeObject` and `SpecificObject.prototype.removeObject`

Comment: I'm sorry, but this was just a typo, the error remains. The Solution from 4castle worked for me.