# JS - Other SO posts say "this" should be preserved in inline function. What have I misunderstood?

Tags: javascript

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37428751/210713) `this` should be preserved, it should refer to the calling object... or so I thought.

So why, in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1Lm4s2v/1/) doesn't the second alert output the same as the first alert?

Comment: "_The enclosing context_" is `window` when you're defining `thing.doStuff`.

Comment: So why, with >3k rep, are you still posting questions that do not _directly_ contain the problematic code, as is _required_ here?

Comment: so you didnt click on the fiddle??