# Calling external objects from $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multithreading, getjson

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't this closure have access to the 'this' keyword? - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323189/why-doesnt-this-closure-have-access-to-the-this-keyword-jquery)

```
function class1() {
    this.url = 'http://en.wikiquote.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&titles=Albert_Einstein&rvprop=content&callback=?';

    this.f = function() {
        $.getJSON(this.url, function() {
            console.log(this.url);
        });
    }
};

var obj = new class1();
obj.f();
```

Instead of printing the url, `obj.f()` prints "undefined" to the console. Why is this happening and what can I do to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your ajax callback, `this` will be the jqXhr object, not your current object.  You'll want to save the value of `this` before your ajax call, and reference *that* in your callback:

```
this.f = function() {
    var self = this;
    $.getJSON(this.url, function() {
        console.log(self.url);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about saving the `url` variable as a local using the `var` statement:

```
function class1() {
    var url = 'http://en.wikiquote.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&titles=Albert_Einstein&rvprop=content&callback=?';

    this.f = function() {
        $.getJSON(url, function() {
            console.log(url);
        });
    }
};
```

This makes the `url` variable private; just be aware of that if you are trying to access the `url` variable outside of the `class1` function.

Comment: but now `url` is private

Comment: True, I was going to update my answer to be more like yours, but then it would be yours... so this remains an option.

Comment: fair enough.  You might consider adding an edit that this will work if OP doesn't mind url no longer being public.