# override google.maps.Marker.prototype.setPosition return error

Tags: javascript, oop, google-maps

catch google.maps.Marker.prototype.setPosition calls

```
(function(){
 var setPos = google.maps.Marker.prototype.setPosition;
 google.maps.Marker.prototype.setPosition = function(latLng){ 
  console.log(["setPos", latLng]);
  setPos(latLng);
 };
})();
```

return error

```
this.set is not a function
http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/cs_ALL/mapfiles/api-3/2/0/main.js
Line 28
```

why? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The initial `google.maps.Marker.prototype.setPosition` would be invoked in the marker's scope, but by storing it in a local variable you change its scope to the local one.

Therefore, the function doesn't have its needed `this` variable. You could try to fix this by using [dojo.hitch](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.2/dojo.hitch), or reading [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025789/preserving-a-reference-to-this-in-javascript-prototype-functions/2025839#2025839)

Also, you should read [this](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/)  about scopes and closures.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly write like,

`markerObject.setPosition(latlng);`

See [Marker methods](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker)

Answer (score 0):

You can always extend the prototype and add your own methods.

```
(function(){
  google.maps.Marker.prototype.oldSetPosition = 
    google.maps.Marker.prototype.setPosition;

  google.maps.Marker.prototype.setPosition = function(latLng){ 
    console.log(["setPos", latLng]);
    this.oldSetPosition(latLng);
  };
})();
```

That way you keep scope intact.