# Global instance in prototypal javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, global-variables, instance

I am exploring a pattern where you can save a global reference to the current instance for simple use in anonymous functions where the `this` keyword is out of context. Consider this:

```
var instance;

var a = function(id) {
  instance = this;
  this.id = id;
};

a.prototype.get = function() {
  return (function() {
    return instance.id;
  })();
};


var x = new a('x');
var y = new a('y');

console.log(x.get());
console.log(y.get());
```

This obviously won't work since instance is defined in the constructor, to each time `.get()` is called, `instance` will reference the last constructed object. So it yields 'y' both times.

However, I'm looking for a way to grab the instance inside a prototype method without using the `this` keyword, to make the code more readable. Singletons is not an option here, I need the prototypal inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: Since you're avoiding to store "local instances", there are some approaches, for example:

Using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/apply) to change the `this` value of the invoked function:

```
var a = function (id) {
  this.id = id;
};

a.prototype.get = function () {

  return (function() {
    return this.id; // the inner `this` value will refer to the value of outside
  }).call(this); 
};
```

Using an argument:

```
//..
a.prototype.get = function () {

  return (function(instance) {
    return instance.id;
  })(this); 
};
```

The new ECMAScript 5th Edition introduced the `bind` method, which is extremely useful to persist the `this` value and optional bound arguments, you can find a compatible implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025789/preserving-a-reference-to-this-in-javascript-prototype-functions/2025839#2025839):

```
//..
a.prototype.get = function() {
  var boundFunction = (function () {
    return this.id;
  }).bind(this);

  return boundFunction(); // no matter how the function is invoked its `this`
};                        // value will always refer to the instance.
```

Comment: yea, exactly. I'm looking for a way to avoid saving local instances for each prototype method when using anonymous functions.

Comment: I guess that's a "no", but thanks for providing patterns for bringing the context into anonymous functions.