# JavaScript scoping with closure: help me understand

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

Running the following code:

```
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) { 
   setTimeout( function() { console.log(i); } , 500 ); 
}
```

Outputs "3" three times. It's outputting the final value of `i` as opposed to the value of `i` when the inner function is created.

If I want the output to be 1, 2, and 3, how would I write this code? How can I get it to use the value of `i` at the time the function is defined as opposed to its final value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
   setTimeout( function(val) { return function() { console.log(val); } }(i), 500 );
}
```

So, at `setTimeout` time (at the time we define the function for `setTimeout`), we're calling the anonymous function taking `val` as a parameter.  This creates a closure for each function call, storing the value of `val` within the scope of the function we just called.  I used a [self-invoking function](http://www.lovemikeg.com/blog/2008/08/17/a-week-in-javascript-patterns-self-invocation/), which creates an immediate [closure](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml).

In the code you provided, the code creates a closure, but for the larger scope of the entirety of the code, so `i` is local to the whole code, meaning that at run-time, the anonymous function will use the variable `i` that the rest of the code uses.

Comment: This example uses two anonymous functions, whereas @z5h's answer uses a named function, which may illustrate the concept more clearly.

Answer (score 4):

```
function f(i){
  return function(){console.log(i);};
}

for (var i=0; i<3; i++) { 
   setTimeout( 
     f(i)
   , 500 ); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The modern alternative to an explicit closure (which can get a bit hairy to read when you've got a double-wrapped function) is `Function#bind`. Once you've [hacked in support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025789/preserving-a-reference-to-this-in-javascript-prototype-functions/2025839#2025839) for browsers that don't do ECMAScript Fifth Edition yet, you can say:

```
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(i) { console.log(i); }.bind(window, i), 500);
}
```

the `window` is the value that `this` will be inside the function (you don't need a `this` here, so we just use the default global object). In the case where you're just calling another function/method, like here with `console.log`, you can use that to excise the function expression completely:

```
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, i), 500);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

alternative:

```
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
   (function(val){
       setTimeout(function() {
           console.log(val);
       },500)
   }(i));
}
```