# Javascript closure "stores" value at the wrong time

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm trying to have a counter increase gradually. The following works:

```
function _award(points){    
  var step = 1;
  while(points){
    var diff = Math.ceil(points / 10);
    setTimeout( "_change_score_by("+diff+");" /* sigh */,
                step * 25);
    points -= diff;
    step++;
  }
}
```

However, it uses an implicit eval. Evil! Let's use a closure instead, right?

```
function _award(points){    
  var step = 1;
  while(points){
    var diff = Math.ceil(points / 10);
    setTimeout( function(){ _change_score_by(diff); },
                step * 25);
    points -= diff;
    step++;
  }
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. All closures created catch the last value `diff` has had in the function -- 1. Hence, all anonymous functions will increase the counter by 1 and, for example, `_award(100)` will increase the score by 28 instead.

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known problem. But you can easily create a closure on each loop iteration:

```
(function(current_diff) {
    setTimeout(function() {_change_score_by(current_diff);},
               step * 25);
})(diff);
```

Comment: Using Functional.js you could create the function to pass to `setTimeout()` like this: `_change_score_by.saturate(diff)` and you wouldn't need the anonymous function.

Comment: I guess you'd then have to also pass `step` as a parameter?

Comment: @badp No. _setTimeout(param1, param2)_ is executed right this moment. Only 'inside' of function _param1_ isn't evaluated (it's executed later, as you noted in your post).

Comment: I wouldn't really call this a "problem".  It's just the way lexical scope is defined in Javascript.

Comment: @Pointy Feature, then :)  It's just that probably every js programmer makes this mistake once. (I did, at least)

Comment: *"This is a known problem"* It's not a problem. It's a feature. Without it, JavaScript would be *dramatically* more limited.

Comment: @Nikita - yes, it's certainly one of the more popular Javascript topics on Stackoverflow!

Comment: Word! Just did this myself.. :S

Answer (score 3):

Solving the Closure Loop Problem gets less messy with ECMAScript Fifth Edition's `Function#bind` method:

```
setTimeout(_change_score_by.bind(window, diff), step*25);
```

You can [hack this feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025789/preserving-a-reference-to-this-in-javascript-prototype-functions/2025839#2025839) into browsers that don't support it yet to get the benefit now.

Answer (score 2):

[Nikita's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953746/javascript-closure-stores-value-at-the-wrong-time/3953762#3953762) works (thanks!), but personally I prefer changing it to this more explicit way:

```
function _schedule_score_change(diff, step){
  setTimeout( function(){ _change_score_by(diff) },
              step*25 );
}

function _award(points){    
  var step = 1;
  while(points){
    var diff = Math.ceil(points / 10);
    _schedule_score_change(diff, step);
    points -= diff;
    step++;
  }
}
```