# Preserving this inside instance Object of class

Tags: javascript, scope, this

my question is probably identical and have same motive as this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025789/preserving-a-reference-to-this-in-javascript-prototype-functions) i ain't using jQuery. I would like a javascript solution.

my object looks like below:

```
function Person(name, age, weight) {
    this._name = name;
    this._weight = weight;
    this._age = age;
    this.Anatomy = {
        Weight: this._weight,
        Height: function () {
            //calculate height from age and weight
            return this._age * this._weight;

//yeah this is stupid calculation but just a demonstration
//not to be intended and here this return the Anatomy object
//but i was expecting Person Object. Could someone correct the 
//code. btw i don't like creating instance and referencing it 
//globally like in the linked post
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.Anatomy = {
          //'this' here will point to Person
    this.f = function() {
         // 'this' here will point to Anatomy.
    } 
}
```

Inside functions `this` generally points at the next thing up a level. The most consistent way to solve this would be

```
this.Anatomy = {
    _person: this,
    Weight: this._weight,
    Height: function () {
        //calculate height from age and weight
        return _person._age * _person._weight;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can do this

```
function Person(name, age, weight) {
    this.Anatomy = {
        weight: weight,
        height: function() { return age*weight; }
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks for that neat tip but creating a private variable that references Person object is this my only way out?? can't i do anything else to solve the problem

Comment: @Deeptechtons you can also just use the arguments which are in scope directly.