# Why did my callback lose its scope?

Tags: javascript

When `test.testHello(helloWorld.sayHello);` runs, it doesn't recognize that I have inserted a new greeting is the greeting is undefined. I can use bind to make sure it runs it in the proper scope, I am not really sure why isn't it running in the proper scope to begin with. Could someone explain why this is happening and show me a better solution?

Solution: `test.testHello(helloWorld.sayHello.bind(helloWorld));`

http://jsfiddle.net/EzabX/

```
var HelloWorldClass = function() {


 this.greetings = [];
}
HelloWorldClass.prototype.addGreeting = function(greeting) {
    this.greetings.push(greeting);
}
HelloWorldClass.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += this.greetings;
    this.greetings.forEach(function(greeting) {
        greeting.execute();        
    })
}

var TestClass = function() {
    this.testHello = function(callback) {
        alert("TestHello is working, now callback");
        callback();
    }
}


var main = function() {
    var helloWorld = new HelloWorldClass();
    var test = new TestClass();
    helloWorld.addGreeting({
        execute: function() {
            alert("Konichiwa!");
        }
    });
    helloWorld.sayHello();

    test.testHello(helloWorld.sayHello);
}

main();
```

Comment: what scope are you talking about ?

Comment: Another way to think about it is `this` isnt a reference to construction context/scope. It's a reference to the *invoker* of a function. Who or what is invoking `callback`? Not `helloWorld`. `bind` gives you a function where the invoker is stable

Answer (score 0):

Managing the `this` variable within the prototype function scope when called as a callback can be complicated for novice users.  You don't always need a prototype for all functions on a class.  If you really want to use a prototype function look at Javascript .bind(this) implementations.  Google and Stackoverflow are your friend on that topic. Example: [Preserving a reference to "this" in JavaScript prototype functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025789/preserving-a-reference-to-this-in-javascript-prototype-functions)

Offending code with `this` referring to DOM Window object and not a HelloWorld instance:

```
this.greetings.forEach(function(greeting) {
        greeting.execute();        
    })
```

A non-prototype version that works just great, easy to use. Fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/EzabX/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/EzabX/1/)

```
var HelloWorldClass = function() {
    var greetings = [];

    this.greetings = greetings;

    this.addGreeting = function(greeting) {
        greetings.push(greeting);
    };

    this.sayHello = function() {
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += greetings;
        greetings.forEach(function(greeting) {
        greeting.execute();        
        })
    }; }
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `greetings`. What exactly do you think is offending in that snippet?

Comment: 'this' refers to Window and not HelloWorld.  Not sure how a working answer and the correct links to other working answer is down voted.  Tweaked the offending line.

Comment: In the `helloWorld.addGreeting(…)` call, `this` *does* refer to `helloWorld`. I didn't downvote because of the link, but because of wrong terms ("scope"), wrong explanation, and hardly helpful code suggestion.

Comment: Inside the forEach callback? Yes, but `this` is not used there, only `greeting`.

Comment: Oh wait, you refer to the `sayHello` call… Yeah, there it doesn't work, but your example code doesn't either.

Comment: It makes the third call in JSfiddle using sayHelloa, just checked in the chrome debugger again. I have fixed the scope word, yup that was just a typo from rewriting a sentence too quickly.

Comment: Yeah, but you're still using `this.greetings` which resolves to `undefined`

Comment: Are you looking at: http://jsfiddle.net/EzabX/1/ ?  I am assigning it, but not using it.  I am using a locally scoped variable within the 'constructor'.   Also fixed formatting to make it more clear in the stack answer.

Comment: Yes I do, it's outputting `undefined` into the `innerHTML`

Comment: What is that line meant to do anyhow?  I agree with your point but the question was around the callback?  I have at least removed the `this`. Thanks.