# Using jQuery in object method defined via MyObject.prototype.method and the 'this' variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, methods, this

I'm currently diving into Object-oriented programming in JavaScript and I came across a problem. I'm defining an object like below, doing some jQuery stuff inside one of the methods, and I'm wondering what is the best way to access Object properties inside a jQuery method that overrides the 'this' variable.

```
function MyObject() {
    this.foo = 'bar';
}

MyObject.prototype.myMethod = function () {
    $.get('myurl', function (data) {
        // how to address this.foo here ?
    });
};
```

Comment: In ECAMScript 6 (though  presently in Firefox), you'll be able to use this syntax: `$.get('myurl', (data) => { console.log(this.foo); })`

Comment: Found a similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025789/preserving-a-reference-to-this-in-javascript-prototype-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save a reference to `this` before calling `$.get`.

```
MyObject.prototype.myMethod = function () {
    var that = this;
    $.get('myurl', function (data) {
        console.log(that.foo);
    });
};
```

Comment: The use of a variable named `that` to save a reference to an outer `this` is a common JavaScript pattern.

Comment: This sounds a bit redundant since I'll have to do it for every method of my object but if there is no other way.. What if the method is defined inside the object function itself ? `var MyObject = function () { this.foo = 'bar'; var self = this; this.myMethod = function () { /* jQuery code here */ } }` this way the `self` variable is defined only once.. ?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a variable in the scope of the outer function to preserve its context:

```
MyObject.prototype.myMethod = function () {
    var self;
    self = this;
    $.get('myurl', function (data) {
        // how to address this.foo here ?
        self.doStuff();
    });
};
```

For callbacks, you may want to make use of [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), which is jQuery's souped-up version of [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
function MyObject(selector) {
    this.foo = 'bar';
    $(selector).on('click', $.proxy(this, 'myMethod'));
}
MyObject.prototype.myMethod = function (e) {
    console.log(this.foo); //'bar'
};
```

For your case specifically, you can make use of `jQuery.proxy` to generate a callback for the `$.get` success function:

```
MyObject.prototype.myMethod = function () {
    $.get('myurl', $.proxy(this, 'myCallback'));
};
MyObject.prototype.myCallback = function (data) {
    console.log(this.foo); //'bar'
};
```

Alternatively, you can write the proxy inline:

```
MyObject.prototype.myMethod = function () {
    $.get('myurl', $.proxy(function (data) {
        console.log(this.foo); //'bar'
    }, this));
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The specific case solution passing `this` to the callback via `jQuery.proxy` is not a bad idea but gets quite messy when multiple jQuery methods are nested and `this` must be available at every level.

Comment: @beeb, that's why I first showed it using a prototype method. It helps to [flatten arrow code](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/). Otherwise I'd recommend taking advantage of queueing and promises, which also help to flatten asynchronous arrow code.