# How to reference widget property from methods called from another context

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My jquery-ui widget has some properties that I need to access on a callback. The problem is the context is transient.

Everything I've read says to create my variables in `_create` constructor and to preserve a reference to the widget in `that`:

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("tsp.videoWrapper", {
        options: {
            value: 0,
            playBtnObj: null,
            timeboxElement: null,
            chapterNavElement: null,
            segmentBarElement: null,
            positionViewElement : null
        },
        _create: function () {
            var that = this;
            var thatElm = $(that.element);
            that.Video = thatElm.children("video")[0];
            if (that.Video == null) {
                console.log("Video element not found.");
                return;
            }
            that._addHandlers();             
        },
        _addHandlers: function () {
            this.Video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", this._videoInited, false);
            if (this.Video.readyState >= this.Video.HAVE_METADATA) {
                this._videoInited.apply(this.Video); // missed the event
            }
        },
        _videoInited: function (evt) {
            console.log(this);
            console.log(this.Video.textTracks[0]);
        });
}(jQuery));
```

Trying to reference `that` in `_videoInit` creates an error:

> Use of an implicitly defined global variable

But the:

```
console.log(this);
```

in `_videoInit` refers to the video itself so calling

```
console.log(this.Video.textTracks[0]);
```

fails to because a `video` doesn't have a `Video` property. I've omitted a bunch of other code for simplicity but after this call I actually need a reference to the widget to do something with the cues loaded into the video so just doing this:

```
console.log(this.textTracks[0]);
```

is not an option.

How do i access the context to get at the video and then do something with it using the properties of the widget instance?

So for instance how do I do this?

```
_videoInited: function (evt) {
    // pretend up in _create I had: that.Cues=[]
    that.Cues = that.Video.textTracks[0].cues;
});
```

I can't use `that` because of the implicit error as above and I can't use `this` because `this` is a video element reference not a `videoWrapper` widget reference. And i can't do:

```
    that.Cues = that.Video.textTracks[0].cues;
```

in `_create` because the `cues` and other meta data aren't initiated at that point. It seems like such a basic thing to want to do "access an objects properties from it's methods".

Answer (score 0):

Ok so from this [preserving-a-reference-to-this-in-javascript-prototype-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025789/preserving-a-reference-to-this-in-javascript-prototype-functions#) I got the [jquery bind](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) method. That question is talking about Prototypes which I thought were like static methods but it seems to work.

Setting up the handler:

```
var that = this;
 $(this.Video).bind("loadedmetadata", function (event) {
      event.widget = that; that._videoInited(event); 
});
```

The bind page says to now use the [jquery on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method

```
 var that = this;
 $(this.Video).on("loadedmetadata", function (event) {
          event.widget = that; that._videoInited(event); 
 });
```

And then using as I wanted:

```
 _videoInited: function (evt) {
            console.log(evt); // has a new dynamic widget property
            console.log(this); // refers to the widget
```

Feels a bit weird and loose but seems to work as expected.