# Javascript - referring to "this" in function run upon click

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a method of an object that is called upon click, and the `this` unfortunately refers to the `window` object instead of the object that I want it to be referring to.

I've read a several posts that mention this issue, but I have not found/understood any alternatives for my situation.

Any assistance in which direction to go would be appreciated

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ky32o3kg/)

```
var IceCream = function(flavor) {
  this.tub = 100;
  this.flavor = flavor;
};

IceCream.prototype = {
  scoop: function() {
    this.updateInventory();
    alert("scooping");
  },
  updateInventory: function() {
    this.tub--;
    alert(this.tub);
  }
};

var vanilla = new IceCream("vanilla");
vanilla.scoop();

$('button').click(vanilla.scoop);
```

Comment: $('button').click(vanilla.scoop.bind(vanilla));

Comment: i do not understand the usage of the 'bind' in that instance. Is the bind telling to use the namespae of vanilla

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025789/preserving-a-reference-to-this-in-javascript-prototype-functions 
also updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ky32o3kg/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('button').click(vanilla.scoop.bind(vanilla));
```

Bind, creates a function whose this variable is bound to the given object. In this case vanilla

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button').click(function(){
    vanilla.scoop();
});
```

Change the last line to this should make it work. The `$.fn.click` function takes a callback, with `event` as the first argument,  and binds the element as `this`, not `window`.

------------Edit------------

To make this a little bit cleaner, you can define a function to return a click function. Define your class like so:

```
IceCream.prototype = {
  scoop: function() {
    this.updateInventory();
    alert("scooping");
  },
  updateInventory: function() {
    this.tub--;
    alert(this.tub);
  },
  makeClickFn: function(){
    var self = this;
    return function(event){
        self.scoop();
    };
  }
};
```

And when you need to bind the click function:

```
$('button').click(vanilla.makeClickFn());
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L7e71sLL/

Answer (score 0):

Inside $('button').click() the scope will be of the button. So you need to bind the vanilla scope to the onClick function