# What is the element called on which you call an prototype function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have made a prototype styled function in jQuery, example:

```
// Check if #Example's width/height is completely in a container:
$('#Example').elementWithinBounderiesOf( $('#Container') );
```

Within these functions, I can use `this` or `$(this)` as the object we called the function on, I understand and get this, but:

**How do we name/call/label/refer-to `the element on which we called the function on`?**

I need this for documentation purposes:

```
// elementWithinBounderiesOf($container) - Check if [NAME NEEDED] fits within $container
// Input:  [NAME NEEDED] - the object we're gonna check if it fits in $container
//         $container - the container which should contain the [NAME NEEDED]
// Output: Boolean true/false wether or not the [NAME NEEDED] fits within $container

$.fn.elementWithinBounderiesOf = function ($container) {
   // $(this) is in this example $('#Example'), but could be any other object
   // How do we call this selected object *here, within the function*?
   // The name for object-on-which-we-activated-the-function (but that's quite a long name)
}
```

***Note 1:** This is an example, I do not need a name specific for this case.*
***Note 2:** I do not need to know how to pass a variable in the function, or a reference, or whatever-functionallity, I'm only looking for that name for `object on which the function is activated`*

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean. Given your example code, `$Example` would have to be a variable defined previously which holds a jQuery object. What relevance does scope have?

Comment: `$Example.elementWithinBounderiesOf( $(this).parent() );` should do the task if I understand the fact...

Comment: I've updated my question, I hope this clearifies it a bit better. I find it difficult to phraze as I don't know what it's called, so I can't use the proper term to clearify

Comment: Sorry @john-slegers, was working on an edit myself, I believe redid what you did now :)

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, care to tell me why? Did my best to make a proper question about this.

Comment: @Martijn : All I did was reduce the indentation to 2 characters (for readability's sake) and adding a space between th function name and the `{` (which is common practice). I'm kind of a "readability Nazi", I guess... Oh, and I did not downvote your question. So I can't comment on that...

Comment: I *readabilinazied* the spaces again, should be as you did it :) And the downvote part wasn't towards you, but to whoever did do that :)

Comment: Do you mean you wish to get the "#Example" text inside your function?

Comment: Nope, that would be `this.id`. I'm just looking for that name for `object on which the function is activated`

Comment: You can't use this.id. You'll need to use $(this).attr("id"); as this refers to the pointer to the function call not the object that called it. eg: https://jsfiddle.net/fpvhxwk7/ although I still don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I've always called the object on which the method is called the `context`, but I do not know if this is a standard nomenclature.

Answer (score 1):

Both, `this` and `$(this)`, refere to the element on that the method is called, so in your case `$('#Example')`. `this` referes to the jQuery object, and `$(this)` to the jQuery wrapper around the same.

If you want preserve a context in prototype, look at this question: [Preserving a reference to "this" in JavaScript prototype functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025789/preserving-a-reference-to-this-in-javascript-prototype-functions)

> For preserving the context, the bind method is really useful, it's now
>   part of the recently released ECMAScript 5th Edition Specification,
>   the implementation of this function is simple (only 8 lines long):

```
// The .bind method from Prototype.js 
if (!Function.prototype.bind) { // check if native implementation available
  Function.prototype.bind = function(){ 
    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        object = args.shift(); 
    return function(){ 
      return fn.apply(object, 
        args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))); 
    }; 
  };
}

MyClass.prototype.myfunc = function() {

  this.element.click((function() {
    // ...
  }).bind(this));
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that `$(this)` is the object on which we call the function. But I'm looking for the same of `object-on-which-we-called-the-function`

Comment: `this` does **not** refer to the DOM object. It refers to the jQuery object. Since a jQuery object be be a wrapper around zero or more DOM objects, there isn't a sensible way for `this` to refer to a single DOM object in that context.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer still doesn't answer my question. I get how the functions work, how I use the `this`s and such. I'm only looking for a name

Answer (score 0):

I call it the *jQuery object*, or the *jQuery-wrapped element* to be really clear. These are the terms used in the [jQuery docs](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/).

Answer (score -1):

As shown by this test case:

```js
$.fn.example = function example () {
    alert(this === myobject);
};

var myobject = $("div");
myobject.example();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`this` is the jQuery object upon which the method was called.

Since `$(some_jquery_object)` creates a new jQuery object with the same members as the one passed in as an argument, `$(this)` will be a different, but identical, jQuery object.