# Why can't I store a reference to $(elem).show and call it later?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[See the jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ebn1f2dt/2/)

When I run the code below:

```
  var divs = $('div');

  // The first three methods of showing a div work
  divs.eq(0).show();
  (divs.eq(1).show)();
  var f = function() {
    divs.eq(2).show();
  }
  f();

  // But this doesn't. Why?
  var g = divs.eq(3).show;
  g();
```

The last method doesn't show the div, and there's no error in the console. I want to use it because I want to store the function concisely without creating an anonymous function block. This is what I would normally do in Python. I can't understand what goes wrong here.

EDIT: the comments aren't really helping me understand the problem. How did `this` get lost? What did it change to and why? Why doesn't that happen with `(divs.eq(1).show)();`?

Comment: That's an interesting question!

Comment: `.show()` depends on the value of `this`, which changes when you separate accessing the method and calling it into individual steps. [Preserving a reference to “this” in JavaScript prototype functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025789/preserving-a-reference-to-this-in-javascript-prototype-functions) and [How does the “this” keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: result is a function with no context

Comment: Because the execution context has changed and the `this` no longer points to your `div`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski why doesn't that happen with `(divs.eq(1).show)();`? Wrapping in parentheses seems like it should have the same effect as storing in a variable. They're both just creating new expressions.

Comment: Frankly I don't understand why you need to store reference to `.show` method. It's more convenient/usable to store **context** (reference to element), then invoke method within it.

Comment: @hindmost I'm passing the function as an argument to another function.

Comment: @AlexHall The grouping operator doesn't seem to alone impact the engine's ability to track the context object for the "method" call. However, involving another operator, such as the comma operator, will impact it – `(null, divs.eq(3).show)()`.

Comment: @AlexHall it seems unlikely that the `(.....show)()` would actually work

Comment: @Alnitak but it does, it's in the fiddle. I got it wrong originally but I edited.

Comment: _I'm passing the function as an argument to another function._ That's not just a _function_, that's a **method** with context which is lost (as it has been wrote many times above) when you store that method in a variable

Comment: @hindmost right, which is what I'm learning, but you said you didn't understand why I want to do this.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski ok, that one gets a 'WAT?!' from me.  I would have read the braces as creating an unbound function reference, without context.

Comment: @Alnitak It seems to be due to [the operator not using `GetValue()` itself](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-grouping-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation). The spec calls out `delete` and `typeof` as reasons for that (I'm assuming to avoid breaking `delete (obj.foo);`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already explained in the comments, it doesn't work because `show()` depends on the value of `this`.

The value of `this` depends on how a function is **called**:

- When called as a "normal" function (`foo()`), `this` will refer to the global object or `undefined` (when in strict mode).
- When called as object method (`obj.foo()`), `this` refers to the object (`obj`).

Understanding how `this` works in JS is crucial. See:

- [YDKJS - this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md)
- [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)
- [Preserving a reference to "this" in JavaScript prototype functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025789/preserving-a-reference-to-this-in-javascript-prototype-functions)

Comment: Why? Why not preserve the value of `this`? I could get the global object or `undefined` easily at any time.

Comment: @Alex: Because functions are first class objects. They don't belong to anything. Consider the following: `var foo = {bar: function() {}}; var foo2 = {bar: foo.bar};`. When I call `foo2.bar()`, what should `this` refer to? It's simply how JavaScript was designed and what makes it so flexible. Python is different because class methods are automatically bound to instances.

Comment: E.g. in Python if you had two instances of the same class and did `inst.method == inst2.method`, you would get `false`, in JavaScript you'd get `true` (assuming the methods have been added to the prototype). Python autobinds methods to new instances (which effectively creates a new function for each instance), JavaScript doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `g()`, the value of `this` is not set to `divs.eq(3)`. Here's one way to fix it.

```
divs.eq(0).show();
(divs.eq(1).show)();
var f = function() {
  divs.eq(2).show();
}
f();

var div3 = divs.eq(3);
var g = div3.show;
g.call(div3);
```

Comment: *"the value of `this` is set to the calling function"* No it isn't.

Comment: @FelixKling my mistake. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

`divs.eq(3).show` is this function code (check it out by `console.log(g)` ):

```
(a,d,e){return null==a||"boolean"==typeof a?c.apply(this,arguments):this.animate(mb(b,!0),a,d,e)}
```

That `this` is what people have been refering to.

The function `g` needs to apply to something. That something, in the first case was `a jQuery element` (the div). In the second case though, it's the `#document` element.

Comment: Why the document element? What would the purpose of that be?

Comment: Originally, the `g` function was part of the jQuery object. You "took a copy of the function out of the element" by making the reference. Since now `g` belongs to the document (remember that `document.ready` context), it applies there.

Comment: *"it's the #document element."* - Isn't it `window`?

Comment: @nnnnnn No, do a console.log(this) on the fiddle to verify.

Comment: Let me rephrase that more assertively: `this` *is* `window`. You are confusing the value of `this` within the ready handler (`document`) with the value of `this` within the `show` method as referenced by `g` (`window`). If you want to check using `console.log(this)` you have to add that inside `show()`.

Comment: (Or in strict mode it should be `undefined`.)