# how can I access "this" variable from a for-of loop in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I access `this` variable from a for-of loop in typescript?  Here's my sample for-of loop:

```
    //for each author qs param
    for (let author of qsParams.authors)
    {
        //check for match by id
        var matches = this.vm.Authors.filter(x => x.id == author);

        //if no match then continue
        if (matches.length == 0) continue;

        //select author
        this.authorSelected(matches[0]);
    }
```

The `this` keyword does not have access to the parent class as expected.  I did a basic google but did not find the answer for getting a handle to `this` within a for-of loop.

**UPDATE**

I could add the following reference above the for-of loop but it seems kind of hacky:

```
    var that = this;

    //for each author qs param
    for (let author of qsParams.authors)
    {
        //check for match by id
        var matches = that.vm.Authors.filter(x => x.id == author);

        //if no match then continue
        if (matches.length == 0) continue;

        //select author
        that.authorSelected(matches[0]);
    }
```

Do you have a more elegant way than `var that=this`; or is this there no better way?

Comment: There should be no issue with `this` in the code you show. Please edit your question into a [mcve] that shows the problem.

Comment: this will target the object of an class instance. It depends what class/function this for loop is embedded in

Comment: Edited question is still not sufficient to reproduce the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserving a reference to "this" in JavaScript prototype functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025789/preserving-a-reference-to-this-in-javascript-prototype-functions)

Answer (score -2):

The problem is not that you have a `for/of` loop. The problem is that the containing method was called from a context where its `this` was lost. See one of the hundreds of other TypeScript questions about `this` for how to have this not happen.

Comment: If this is a dupe, please vote to close it as a dupe.