# Destructuring a function from object ( Date Object )

Tags: javascript, date, methods, this, destructuring

If i want to destruct an Object i would do :

```js
const obj = {
  a: 'a',
  fn: () => 'some function'
}

// const fn = obj.fn;
// OR

const {
  a,
  fn
} = obj;

console.log( fn() );
```

this doesn't work for the `Date` Object :

> Uncaught TypeError: this is not a Date object.

```js
const date = new Date();

const day = date.getDate();
console.log(day); // works

const {
  getDate
} = date;
console.log( getDate() ); // doesn't work
```

Why is this possible with the first Object and not with the `Date` ? how would one acheive that if it's possible.

Comment: Destructuring is just a shorthand for `name = obj.name` and in both cases you loose `this` context of the `obj`.  As such this is not limited to dates, any obj will loose `this`.

Comment: The 2 date examples are not equivalent. Your destructuring is like this: `const getDate = date.getDate; getDate()` which makes little sense without `date` object being `this` https://stackoverflow.com/a/2025839

Comment: From [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date.prototype.setdate): *Let t be LocalTime(? thisTimeValue(this value)).*. What is *this* when you call the destructured *getDate*? You can fix it with `getDate.call(date)`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG the question in your comment helped understanding what's happening, makes much sense now, when i destructure a function i loose *this*, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `this` it not a Date object. When you call `getDate()` without its proper context (ie. `date.getDate()`), then you're calling it in the context of the `window` (or `null` in strict mode). Neither `window` nor `null` are Date objects, therefore the function fails.

Try `const getDate = date.getDate.bind(date);`

Demo:

```js
const test = { fn : function() { return this.constructor; } };

const normal = test.fn();
console.log(normal); // object

const {fn} = test;
console.log( fn() ); // window

const bound = test.fn.bind(test);
console.log( bound() ); // object
```

Comment: @ABOS So...? The question doesn't have anything to do with destructors, it's asking about destructuring.

Comment: The title said destruct, so I thought OP wanted to do it that way.

Comment: @ABOS: That's the main point of this answer.  Destructuring here gives you a bare function reference, and not a bound method.  If you can find a way to do this with destructuring, we're all ears.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, I think the difficulty is how to write a 'one-liner' using destruct, if doing it in plain assignment like `f = date.getDate, f()`, I am pretty it has been discussed a lot on SO before...

Comment: @ABOS: I'm not following.  `f = date.getDate, f()` has exactly the same issue as described in the question.

Comment: Please don't confuse "context" with "this". If a function is called in a window (global) **execution** context, the fact that its *this* defaults to the window object has nothing to do with the context it was called from. So *this* is not "context". Similarly for arrow functions, where *this* is adopted from its outer execution context.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely not worth it, but you could write a function to help you destructure methods from an object.  Here `bindMethods` does this, using helper `allKeys`, which collects the keys from the entire prototype chain of an object and which in turn depends on `walkPrototypeChain`.  They could obviously be folded into a single function if desired.

```js
const walkPrototypeChain = (process, init, finish) => (obj) => {
  let currObj = obj, currRes = init();
  do {
    currRes = process(currRes, currObj)
  } while (currObj = Object.getPrototypeOf(currObj))
  return finish(currRes)
}

const allKeys = walkPrototypeChain(
  (set, obj) => {Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(k => set.add(k)); return set},
  () => new Set(),
  s => [...s]
)

const bindMethods = (obj) => allKeys(obj).reduce(
  (o, n) => typeof obj[n] == 'function' ? ({...o, [n]: obj[n].bind(obj)}) : o, 
  {}
)

const date = new Date()
const {getDate, getFullYear} = bindMethods(date) // or any other date function

console.log(getDate())
console.log(getFullYear())
```