# I'm trying to call a JavaScript function but I cannot access it as apparently it is 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, function, methods, addeventlistener, event-listener

I'm trying to call a JavaScript function (apiCall) using an event listener binded to a drop-down list listening for a change.

I want the function to re-run when a different menu item is selected from the drop-down list, but when I run this code, the error occurs on the event listener saying that 'apiCall' is not defined, even though it clearly is right above.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

```
// API CALL 
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open('GET', base + forecast + key + city, true)

request.onload = function apiCall() {
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
  console.log(data)
  string = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
  app.innerHTML = string;
}


document.getElementById("locationList").addEventListener("change", apiCall)


//send request
request.send()
```

Comment: Assigning the function to the request.onload property of the XMLHttpRequest is not the same as defining the function with the proper scope.

Comment: make the function anonymous ```request.onload = function(e) {...}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the function first, then assigning it to `request.onload` seems to be working:

```js
var request = {};

function apiCall() {
  console.log('hello');
}

request.onload = apiCall;

request.onload();
apiCall();
```

So your code should be like

```
// API CALL 
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open('GET', base + forecast + key + city, true)

function apiCall() { // <- removed 'request.onload' from here...
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
  console.log(data)
  string = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
  app.innerHTML = string;
}

request.onload = apiCall; // <- and placed it here

const boundApiCall = apiCall.bind(request); // to keep your 'this' object

document.getElementById("locationList").addEventListener("change", boundApiCall)


//send request
request.send()
```

Edit: I see you're using `this` inside your function. I'm not 100% sure (still learning here), but I think the extra `bind` I added will keep your `this` working as previously.

Answer (score 2):

The function which you're assigning to `window.onload` is a function *expression*, not a function *declaration*. A named function expression's name isn't added to the surrounding scope, and so, it is only available locally to the function expression itself. This means you won't be able to reference it later on outside the function:

```js
function iAmAFunctionDeclaration() {
  console.log("abc");
}

+function iAmAFunctionExpression() {
  console.log("abc");
}

console.log(typeof iAmAFunctionDeclaration);
console.log(typeof iAmAFunctionExpression); // undefined (not added to the `window`).
```

Instead, if you can make `apiCall` a function declaration, you'll be able to access its name to execute it later on, as well as assign it as a callback:

```js
function apiCall() {
  console.log("performing api call");
}

window.onload = apiCall;
document.addEventListener("click", apiCall);
```

In order to make your API call work correctly, you can either `.bind()` your `request` to your `apiCall` function as shown by [@Stratubas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6002078/stratubas) or you can replace `this` keyword with `request`. This will allow you to handle what `this` refers to within your callback. For more ways of dealing with `this` inside of a callback, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025789/preserving-a-reference-to-this-in-javascript-prototype-functions).

You can read more about function expressions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Description)

Comment: OP's code has a `this.response`. Will it work properly with your code?

Comment: @Stratubas Hi, thanks for pointing that out. I didn't notice the use of `this` in the callback. I've added a note about dealing with that now. Cheers