# The context of this in a callback function

Tags: javascript

I am dealing with an API where It was a method on the Instance which returns a callback function

```
   myPlayer.onPlay(function() {
            console.log(this)
        })
```

Now I would expect the context of this to be the player but it is not it is the callback function.  I have tried binding the context of this like this but it doesn't work either.

I expected this to be myPlayer as that is the context in which the onPlay function was executed?

```
myPlayer.onPlay(function() {
        console.log(this)
    }).bind(this)
```

How would I get the context to be the instance of the player? Am i missing something?

Comment: what do you expect `this` to be?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I expected this to be myPlayer as that is the context in which the onPlay function was executed?

Comment: `this` is late-bound in JS and by default will be the calling context.

Comment: Usually `.bind(this)` is the correct solution. You can also use an arrow function, which automatically binds `this`. If your solution isn't working, you need to post a [mcve].

Comment: You need to call `.bind()` on the function, not on the return value of `.onPlay()`. And you need to use `.bind(myPlayer)` if you wanted to bind `this` to the player. Although really then you should just refer to the `myPlayer` variable in the function, not to `this`.

Comment: @Barmar But binding here, expecting `this` to be `myPlayer`, seems almost certainly wrong (even if `bind` was called correctly).

Comment: It depends on what myPlayer is doing....

Comment: Try `this.onPlay(...).bind(this)`

Comment: "*I expected this to be myPlayer as that is the context in which the onPlay function was executed?*" - no. We don't know how `onPlay` calls its callback, you haven't shared its code (or linked the library documentation). Nothing in your code indicates what the `this` value would become - [it depends on how it is called](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) internally.

Comment: @Barmar I doubt `onPlay(...)` returns a function

Comment: @MarcusPetty-Saphon To slightly expand on what Bergi is saying--`mPlayer` may or may not bind the provided function to itself, so `this` is indeterminate w/ the information provided.

Comment: @Bergi Right. Maybe `myPlayer.onPlay(function() { ...}.bind(this))` or `myPlayer.onPlay(() => { ... })`

Comment: With code [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/m4vdh6a7/) it works as expected.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369004/this-keyword-in-event-methods-when-using-javascript-prototype-object

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do

```js
myPlayer.onPlay(
  function() {
    console.log(this);
  }.bind(myPlayer)
);
```

Since you haven't provided what `.onPlay` will return, I don't think it would return an object with a `bind` method. So you have to use `bind` on the function itself. You can't use `this` in the bind if you want it to be the `myPlayer`, because in your current call scope `this` doesn't mean something. It can mean something, but it most likely won't be the player, or else you would have done `this.onPlay`. You have to bind `myPlayer` with `bind`, not `this`.